# How to send params in a child route using ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Every time I try to send parameters to this URL

company/1234234/

the urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/') kicks in.

If I don't have the :companyId, it works fine.  Only when you try to send parameters to it does it act up.

```
angular.module('angularApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('root.company', {
        url: 'company/:companyId',
        views: {
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/company/company.html',
                controller: 'CompanyCtrl'
            }
        }    
      })
  })
```

Comment: huh? The url is `company/:companyId`, but you send data to `customer/1234/`. What's up with that?

Comment: You say the url is `customer/1234/` but your route above is looking for `company/1234`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes! Sorry guys, typo!

Comment: @user3527354, Did you fix it ?

Comment: No that was a typo just for the post.  Unfortunately, it still does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working, but still not sure why. All I changed was instead of saying /:companyId, I made it ?companyId.  For whatever reason, it doesn't like the /

```
angular.module('angularApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('root.company', {
        url: 'company?companyId',
        views: {
            'main@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/company/company.html',
                controller: 'CompanyCtrl'
            }
        }    
      })
  })
```